# Ruby build failed using rbenv install 2.1.3 Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, build, rbenv

I want to install ruby 2.1.3 using this command:

```
rbenv install 2.1.3
```

But the result is BUILD FAILED.

I have tried most of the suggestion from Google, but still error. Here is the latest error message:

```
Last 10 log lines:
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
compiling psych_to_ruby.c
installing default psych libraries
linking shared-object nkf.so
linking shared-object psych.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20170129014849.4100/ruby-2.1.3/ext/nkf'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20170129014849.4100/ruby-2.1.3/ext/psych'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20170129014849.4100/ruby-2.1.3'
uncommon.mk:180: recipe for target 'build-ext' failed
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

Comment: is your rbenv configured right? Look up here, this instruction worked for me: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Yeah, I followed that instruction as well. But the result is build failed.

Comment: Did you install ruby-build?
https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build#readme

Comment: yeah, I have installed ruby-build, and can run the rbenv install command

Comment: @mrsptr Did you manage to work this one out? I'm having the same issues.

Comment: It's only last 10 log lines. You should post whole build log. Look for phrase "Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.<timestamp>.log"